# IOS multi step form

Tags: ios, forms

First of all, I'm completely new to IOS and XCode. I need to create a form which has multiple steps, because I need to validate some of the information before moving on to the next steps.

Basically what I need to accomplish is the exact same thing asked on this post: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/ios-multi-step-form-and-user-input-validation

The answer provided in this question is exactly what I need to accomplish. The problem is that I don't understand how to achieve this. I've looked through countless tutorials using the Page View Controller but they aren't similar to what I need to accomplish, I'm also having a hard time understanding them since I'm so new to Xcode. Can anyone please provide an example of how to achieve something like this? I would appreciate **ANY** help or guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use navigation view controller.

Have multiple view controllers...Each view controller is Form ...If validation is success push the next view controller like that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to achieve. However, I'm not sure how since I can't find any tutorial doing something like this. Could you provide any links to any tutorial?

Comment: Just search like "How to use navigation controller","How to perform validation in textfield validation in iOS" like that it'll lead you to lots of tutorial